# If toLocaleString() fed with timezone, will it return the Daylight saving's time automatically?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, utc

I have the below snippet which converts the current Date object to the EST time and date. My question is, will it return the Date and Time of EST (Auto adjusting Daylight saving's time? ). Currently it is returning the exact time of EST timezone.

`const date = new Date(); let d = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'America/New_York', dateStyle: 'short', timeStyle: 'short'}); console.log(d);`

I tried with the above code snippet, I'm getting the expected answer, but want to know will it return the correct time when the DST (Daylight saving time) gets over for US.

**Expected result: **

***Example:***
When DST : 05:00 AM (getting as expected)
When No DST: 04:00 AM (Don't know what will it return when DST gets over)

UTC offset for EST during DST is -4
UTC offset for EST during DST is -5

Comment: why don't you try it? (it does)

Comment: @JaromandaX, US is in the DST now, if i try to run the code it returns the time with DST only. I'm not sure How can i test it.

Comment: @Kameysh, you can change your `pc/labtop` locale time to date before DST, and test.

Comment: add 6 months to the date ... see the time change by one hour ... profit

Comment: @JaromandaX, according to google, yes. 

Daylight saving time 2022 in United States began at 2:00 am on
Sunday, 13 March
and ends at 2:00 am on
Sunday, 6 November

Comment: ignore my comment about DST in america, I got confused :p ... by the way ... some of america is going to move permanently to DST :p

Comment: @JaromandaX, so no matter how it changes, the above snippet will be returning me the correct time which is in the US right? :)

Comment: correct, that's what all those arguments to `toLocaleString` do

Comment: @Kamesh—the point of IANA representative locations (aka "timezones") like America/New_York is to accommodate all historic offset changes for that location, including pre–20th century offsets based on local solar noon, various periods where  DST was and wasn't observed, changes to local standard time (such as "permanent DST"), and so on. The related "timezone" is the area formed by all nearby locations that have the same offset history.